# Donut Chart connect all arcs

Tags: svg, charts

Drawing svg donut chart using circle. I need to connect all arcs, instead gap between them. is it possible?
I set stroke-dasharray="${item.percent} 100" but it doesn't work. also I set  pathLength="${100+0*arr.length}" but it doesn't work either. See the code below

```js
var DonutSlice = [{
      id: 1,
      percent: 60,
      color: 'DarkSeaGreen',
      label: 'Slice 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      percent: 30,
      color: 'DarkOrchid',
      label: 'Slice 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      percent: 10,
      color: 'Tomato',
      label: 'Slice 3'
    }
    ];

    var circlecontainer = document.getElementById('circlecontainer');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    circlecontainer.innerHTML = DonutSlice.map((item, i, arr) => {
      let offset = 1 * i + arr.filter((item, j) => j < i)
        .reduce((total, item) => total + item.percent, 0);
      return `<circle data-id="${item.id}" stroke="${item.color}"
          cx="80" cy="80" r="79" class="slice"
          pathLength="${100+0*arr.length}"
          stroke-dasharray="${item.percent} 100"
          stroke-dashoffset="-${offset}" />`;
    }).join('');

    circlecontainer.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      let slice = e.target.closest('.slice');
      if (slice) {
        item = DonutSlice.find(item => item.id == parseInt(slice.dataset.id));
        output.innerHTML = `${item.label} was clicked`;
      }
    });
```

```css
  .slice {
    /* stroke-linecap: round; */
    stroke-width: 15;
    fill: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  p#output {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
  <div style="width: 200px">
    <svg class="svg2" width="174" height="174" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 174 174" version="1.1">
      <circle fill="#000000" cx="87" cy="87" r="87" />
      <g id="circlecontainer" transform="rotate(0 0 0)"></g>
    </svg>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using stroke-dashoffset I prefer to use transform rotate. So the offset value needs to be a number of degrees. I added `/ 100 * 360` to the calculation.

If you use the circlecontainer group to position the chart you can skip the cx and cy attributes on the circle elements.

##### Update

There was a gap between the slices. I changed the pathLength to 360 so that is matches the rotation. Then I add 1 degree to the length of the slice and rotate the slice 1 degree. Now, the end of each slice will overlap the slice next to it.

```js
var DonutSlice = [{
      id: 1,
      percent: 60,
      color: 'DarkSeaGreen',
      label: 'Slice 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      percent: 30,
      color: 'DarkOrchid',
      label: 'Slice 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      percent: 10,
      color: 'Tomato',
      label: 'Slice 3'
    }
    ];

    var circlecontainer = document.getElementById('circlecontainer');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    circlecontainer.innerHTML = DonutSlice.map((item, i, arr) => {
      let offset = arr.filter((item, j) => j < i)
        .reduce((total, item) => total + item.percent, 0) / 100 * 360;
      return `<circle data-id="${item.id}" stroke="${item.color}"
          r="72" class="slice"
          pathLength="360"
          stroke-dasharray="${item.percent / 100 * 360 + 1} 360"
          transform="rotate(${offset - 1})" />`;
    }).join('');

    circlecontainer.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      let slice = e.target.closest('.slice');
      if (slice) {
        item = DonutSlice.find(item => item.id == parseInt(slice.dataset.id));
        output.innerHTML = `${item.label} was clicked`;
      }
    });
```

```css
.slice {
    /* stroke-linecap: round; */
    stroke-width: 16;
    fill: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  p#output {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
    <svg class="svg2" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164 164">
      <circle fill="#000000" cx="84" cy="84" r="80" />
      <g id="circlecontainer" transform="translate(80 80) rotate(-90)"></g>
    </svg>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Chrwahl, Thanks for your reply, there is still about 1px gap between arc, if zoomed. is there way to remove it? Thank you

Comment: @Ryan I added an update to my answer. I hope that is helps.

Comment: Hi Chrwahl, if  Iset one of the percent, then it show 1px gap between opening and closing arc. for example,  var DonutSlice = [
        {
          id: 1,
          percent: 100,
          color: 'DarkSeaGreen',
          label: 'Slice 1',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          percent: 0,
          color: 'DarkOrchid',
          label: 'Slice 2',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          percent: 0,
          color: 'Tomato',
          label: 'Slice 3',
        },
      ];

Comment: I did following updates: circlecontainer.innerHTML = DonutSlice.map((item, i, arr) => {
        let offset =
          (arr
            .filter((item, j) => j < i)
            .reduce((total, item) => total + item.percent, 0) /
            100) *
          360;
        return `<circle data-id="${item.id}" stroke="${item.color}"
          r="72" class="slice"
          pathLength="100"
          stroke-dasharray="${(item.percent / 100) * 360} 360"
          transform="rotate(${offset})" />`;
      }).join(''); it works fine in all browser except ipad chrome and safari

Answer (score 0):

Your offset calculation adds a gap.
Change it to (delete the additional `1 * i +`):

```
let offset = arr.filter((item, j) => j < i)
        .reduce((total, item) => total + item.percent, 0);
```

```js
var DonutSlice = [{
    id: 1,
    percent: 60,
    color: 'DarkSeaGreen',
    label: 'Slice 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    percent: 30,
    color: 'DarkOrchid',
    label: 'Slice 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    percent: 10,
    color: 'Tomato',
    label: 'Slice 3'
  }
];

var circlecontainer = document.getElementById('circlecontainer');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

circlecontainer.innerHTML = DonutSlice.map((item, i, arr) => {
  let offset = arr.filter((item, j) => j < i)
    .reduce((total, item) => total + item.percent, 0);

  return `<circle data-id="${item.id}" stroke="${item.color}"
          cx="80" cy="80" r="79" class="slice"
          pathLength="${100+0*arr.length}"
          stroke-dasharray="${item.percent} 100"
          stroke-dashoffset="-${offset}" />`;
}).join('');

circlecontainer.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  let slice = e.target.closest('.slice');
  if (slice) {
    item = DonutSlice.find(item => item.id == parseInt(slice.dataset.id));
    output.innerHTML = `${item.label} was clicked`;
  }
});
```

```css
.slice {
  /* stroke-linecap: round; */
  stroke-width: 15;
  fill: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p#output {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
  <svg class="svg2" width="174" height="174" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 174 174" version="1.1">
    <circle fill="#000000" cx="87" cy="87" r="87" />
    <g id="circlecontainer" transform="rotate(0 0 0)"></g>
  </svg>
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Herrstrietzel, if zoomed it shows gap between orange and green. I need closed arcs. Thank you